# SQL Left Join two tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

List consumer names from Madison and number of computer requests for each (0 if no requests)

Right now the following query says that it can not be bound, and I assume it's because I am trying to LEFT JOIN two tables to Tb_Requests. I don't know any other way around this.

```
   SELECT Tb_Consumer.Name, COUNT(tb_requests.Prod_ID) 'Number of Requests'
     FROM Tb_Consumer, Tb_Product 
LEFT JOIN Tb_Requests 
       ON Tb_Consumer.Con_ID = Tb_Requests.Con_ID
    WHERE Tb_Consumer.City = 'Madison'
      AND Tb_Product.Name = 'Computer'
 GROUP BY Tb_Consumer.Name
```

**I have the following tables:**

Tb_Consumer - Name, City, Con_ID
Tb_Supplier - Name, City, Supp_ID
Tb_Offers - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Supp_ID
Tb_Product - Name, Prod_ID
Tb_Requests - Name, Quantity, Prod_ID, Con_ID
Tb_Transactions - Tran_ID, Supp_ID, Con_ID, Quantity, Price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this issue using the following query:

```
SELECT T1.Name, Count(Tbl_Computer.Prod_ID)
FROM Tbl_Consumer T1 LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT T2.Prod_ID, T2.Con_ID 
      FROM Tb_Requests T2 
           INNER JOIN Tb_Product T3 
           ON T2.Prod_ID = T3.Prod_ID 
      WHERE T3.Name = 'Computer') AS Tbl_Computer
      ON T1.Con_ID = Tbl_Computer.Con_ID 
 WHERE T1.City = 'Madison'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of those are working for me, and yes I edited the errors.

Comment: @WiscoGold for the first query, what was the output. Also i edited the first two query. give them a try

Comment: The second one is working, except not receiving the ones that are 0 if null.

Comment: @WiscoGold man there is some missing data. If the data is correct, the last one will never returns blank. I added a condition to it, please check it again

Comment: The second and the third display the same data. The first one displays all the data I need, just with the "Requests" all showing 1, when two of the outputs should display 0.

Comment: @WiscoGold in the first query if you replaced `Count(*)` with `Count(Tbl_Computer.Prod_ID)` what did you get?

Comment: when I do that, I get the correct answer, thank you. I appreciate everything. I would have never guessed trying this way, it's hard learning from my professor as he just copy and pastes, and doesn't teach through by through, and just having the indentation how you have it teaches me alot. Thanks!

Comment: @WiscoGold if this answer solved your problem you have to accept it, just click on the mark below the voting arrows. Also if you find it helpful you can upvote it

Comment: Thanks again @Hadi